# My code works in JSFiddle but not on local server

Tags: javascript, spotify, jsfiddle

I've seen a lot of questions like this but I feel like I've tried everything from other suggestions and nothing has seemed to work. But in JsFiddle, the alert() function works in the code and an alert box appears, but this is not the case in my own environment when I use local web browser to run my javascript eclipse project. Here is my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Testy</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .container {
        margin: 1em;
    }

    img {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<h1>Displaying User Data</h1>
<p>Log in with your Spotify account and this demo will display information about you fetched using the Spotify Web API</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-login">Login</button>
<button class="btn btn-res" id="btn-res">Result</button>
<div/>




<script src="normalize.css"></script> 
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0-alpha.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
function login(callback) {
    var CLIENT_ID = '04270f76089b4a65a3eb749c0addb583';
    var REDIRECT_URI = 'http://jmperezperez.com/spotify-oauth-jsfiddle-proxy/';
    function getLoginURL(scopes) {
        return 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=' + CLIENT_ID +
          '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(REDIRECT_URI) +
          '&scope=' + encodeURIComponent(scopes.join(' ')) +
          '&response_type=token' +
          '&show_dialog=true';
    }

    var url = getLoginURL([
        'user-library-read playlist-read-private user-follow-read'
    ]);

    var width = 450,
        height = 730,
        left = (screen.width / 2) - (width / 2),
        top = (screen.height / 2) - (height / 2);

    window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
        var hash = JSON.parse(event.data);
        if (hash.type == 'access_token') {
            callback(hash.access_token);
        }
    }, false);

    var w = window.open(url,
                        'Spotify',
                        'menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no, width=' + width + ', height=' + height + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left
                       );

}
function ridDuplicates(artists) { // returns final artists array
        artistsFresh = []; // will contain no duplicate artists
    artistsFresh.push(artists[0]); // first element can't be a duplicate
    for (var i = 1; i < artists.length; i++) {
            var j = i-1;
        var duplicateArt = false;
            while (j >= 0 && duplicateArt == false) {
             if (artistsFresh[j] == artists[i]) {
                duplicateArt = true;
           }
           j--;
        }
        if (!duplicateArt) {
                artistsFresh.push(artists[i]);
        }
    }
    return artistsFresh;
} 

var i = 0;
function getUserData(accessToken, i) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks?limit=50&offset=' + i,
        headers: {
           'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
        }
    });
}


   var loginButton = document.getElementById('btn-login');

var resButton = document.getElementById('btn-res');
var artists = [];
resButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert(artists.length);
});

loginButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
login(function(accessToken) {
    loginButton.style.display = 'none';
    var arr = [getUserData(accessToken, i)];
    arr[0]
    .then(function(response) {
        for (var i = 50; i < response.total; i += 50) {
            arr.push(getUserData(accessToken, i));
        }
        Promise.all(arr).then(function(chunks) {
            var artists = [].concat.apply([], chunks.map(function(response)                    {
                return response.items.map(function(item) {
                    return item.track.album.artists[0].name;
                });
            }));
            // these alert lines do not seem to work 

            alert(artists.length);
            alert(artists[9]);
            var newArray = ridDuplicates(artists);
            alert(newArray.length);

        });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        // handle errors here
    });
});

});
});

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

These alert lines are where I want to perform the actual meat of the program with the data I receive but I haven't been able to get things to function at all here. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is `normalize.css` a JavaScript file? Use the [browser console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) and read the errors and check the Network tab there to confirm that all your resources are found.

Answer (score 3):

When a URL begins with `//`, like `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0-alpha.1/handlebars.min.js`, the browser changes the protocol to match the protocol that the page was served from.  On a local file, this means `file://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0-alpha.1/handlebars.min.js`.  Since you don't have the API installed on your local computer, this won't include the resource.  You should change the URL to `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0-alpha.1/handlebars.min.js`.  Also,

```
<script src="normalize.css"></script>
```

should be changed to:

```
<link href="normalize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: These are issues I didn't see before thank you! However, the original issue was not solved. After further probing, I believe it has to do with the redirect uri. This uri (http://jmperezperez.com/spotify-oauth-jsfiddle-proxy/) was used in the JsFiddle example and works on JsFiddle. However, this throws an error on the console. So I used http://localhost:8888 which works but I still cannot get any functionality at that same spot where the alert()'s are. Do you have any idea how this redirect_uri works in conjunction with the access token and the rest of the script??